# Links in iframe are not triggering decidePolicyForNewWindowAction

Tags: macos, iframe, webview

I have a iframe of youtube player in my webview macos application, and most of the links (the `<a>` element) inside the iframe are not triggering the `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction` delegate.

The only working `<a>` element is the channel link, others like video title, the youtube icon are all silent, and I can't tell the differences between these `<a>`s.

So why are some links cannot trigger `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction`?

Documentation of the delegate: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpolicydelegate/1536381-webview?language=objc

Documentation of the iframe youtube player: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone maybe interested:

Turns out it's not a `iframe` problem, it's because some `<a>` are not directly changing the url, it calls some **javascript** to do the job for it. This was inspected from the callstack.

In such case, **the first thing** is that one more delegate needs to be hooked up, the  `createWebViewWithRequest`. This delegate returns `nil` by default. So change it like this:

```
- (WebView*)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return sender;
}
```

Not doing much but let the following codes continue.

**The second thing** is that the **javascript** url request goes to `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` instead. So still not firing `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction` but at least there's a chance to know it.

In my case I add some condition inside `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` to distinguish my request and iframe's request, like this:

```
- (void) webView: (WebView*) sender decidePolicyForNavigationAction: (NSDictionary*) actionInformation
                                                            request: (NSURLRequest*) request
                                                              frame: (WebFrame*) frame
                                                   decisionListener: (id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>) listener
{
    NSString* mainDocumentURL = [[request mainDocumentURL] absoluteString];
    NSString* fromYT = @"https://www.youtube.com";
    if ([mainDocumentURL hasPrefix:fromYT]) {
        [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url]; // fires Safari
        [listener ignore];
        return;
    }

    // normal flow here, you could open it inside the webview or something
}
```